# What is the difference between declaration "MyStuct a();" and "MyStruct a;"?

Tags: d

This program compiles and links:

```
struct A{
    int m;
}

void main()
{
    A a;
    int x = a.m;
}
```

While this doesn't:

```
struct A{
    int m;
}

void main()
{
    A a();
    int x = a.m;
}
```

`$dmd app.d` returns:

```
app.o: In function `_Dmain':
app.d:(.text._Dmain+0xb): undefined reference to `_D3app4mainFZ1aMFZS3app1A'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am puzzled.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`A a();` is a function declaration - it declares a function called `a` which returns a value of the struct type `A`.`int x = a.m;` then calls the function `a` (parens are optional in D if no arguments are needed), and reads the returned value's `m` field.

Because the function is only declared, but never defined, the program compiles but does not link, as the function `a` doesn't have a body that the linker can see.